# (Re-)Setting the currents section name from within the section

Tags: sectioning, environments, parameters

I am trying to reset the currents section from somewhere "whithin" the section, but after the `\section` command. Is that even possible with the way LaTeX works?
I know, it is possible to use the title of a section within it with the *nameref* package, but is there a way to change/re-set it after it was initially set by `\section{mytitle}`?

The scenario looks like this:

I have created an custom environment, in which the preamble always starts with a

```
\subsubsection{My Content No. \arabic{mycounter}}
```

and afterwards creates a table, in which all of this sections information is displayed. I have set a few `\newcommands` which take arguments and do not much more than make formatted table rows out of it. All of that works fine. But there is also a command

```
\name{TitleOfThisCase}
```

Not in all cases, this command will be used, but when it is used, I would like to overwrite the above argument to the `\subsubsection` command with the provided Title. By default, the section is just numbered, if a name is provided, it the title should be reset. In short, I am looking for something to add to the command definition of `\name` that would do something like

```
\renewcommand{\currentname}{#1 (Case No. \arabic{mycounter})}
```

My code looks sort of like the following, using *supertabular* package:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{supertabular}

\newcommand{\variants}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{l}{\emph{Variants:}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth}}{#1}\\
\hline}
% ...
\newcommand{\name}[1]{Name & #1 \\ \hline }

\newcounter{myCount}
\newenvironment{myEnv}[1][\arabic{myCount}]{
\stepcounter{myCount}
\bgroup
\subsubsection{Env \arabic{myCount}}
\begin{center}
\tablefirsthead{
\hline}
\tablehead{%
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize\sl myEnv \arabic{myCount} (continued)}\\
\hline}
\tabletail{%
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\scriptsize\sl continued on next page \dots}\\
\hline}
\tablelasttail{\hline}
\label{awf:#1}
\begin{supertabular}{p{3.5cm}|p{11.5cm}}
}{
\end{supertabular}
\end{center}
\egroup  
}

\begin{document}

\section{first section}
    \subsection{a subsection}
        \begin{myEnv}[label1]
            \name{My title (this should also reset the title of this section), it is Environment1}
            \variants{some variants to describe}
        \end{myEnv}

        \subsubsection{Another Subsection}
        Another subsubsection, not using the custom environment.

        \begin{myEnv}[label2]
            \variants{this only has variants, and is Environment2, but section 1.1.3}
        \end{myEnv}

\section{Second Section}
    \subsection{another subsection}
        \subsubsection{yet another subsubsection}
        nothing here
        \begin{myEnv}[label3]
            \name{This is my environment with number 3, but section number 2.1.2}
        \end{myEnv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Since `\section` is a macro and not an environment, all effects of issuing `\section` are complete by the time you are "inside" the section.  Thus, I'm fairly confident, it is too late.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Well, I was afraid of hearing that, since I wasn't able to find anybody even asking this. I hoped there would be a way of overwriting the last occurrence (since there is no "whithin" with a macro) of `\section` from later in the document.

Comment: Could you not pass the name as an optional argument to the environment? I don't know what your real case looks like but in your MWE, `\name` directly follows the start of the environment so combining it into the start of the environment looks to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way is to use a `key-value` approach, which controls the generation of the subsubsection title whether `name={}` was given or not. 
However, in this case, the optional `label` argument could not be maintained, but must be a key also, i.e. `label=myLabel`.

If `name={}` was specified, it generates the according table line and it is used for the subsubsectiontitle, otherwise, the table line is not present and the title is `Env \arabic{myCount}`.

A snapshot first:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xkeyval}%
\usepackage{supertabular}
\newcounter{myCount}



\makeatletter
\define@key{CasesFamilyKey}{name}[]{%
\def\CasesKVMacroName{#1}%
}%

\define@key{CasesFamilyKey}{label}[]{%
\def\CasesKVMacroLabel{#1}%
}%
\makeatother



\newcommand{\CreateNameLine}{%
\ifdef{\CasesKVMacroName}{%
Name & \CasesKVMacroName \tabularnewline
\hline
}{%
}%
}%

\newcommand{\CreateSubSubSectionTitle}[1][]{%
\setkeys{CasesFamilyKey}{#1}%
\ifdef{\CasesKVMacroName}{%
\subsubsection{\CasesKVMacroName}}
{%
\subsubsection{Env \arabic{myCount}}
}%
}%

\newcommand{\variants}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{l}{\emph{Variants:}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth}}{#1}\\
\hline}
% ...
\newcommand{\name}[1]{Name & #1\\ \hline}

\newenvironment{myEnv}[1][]{%
\setkeys{CasesFamilyKey}{#1}%
\stepcounter{myCount}
\bgroup
\CreateSubSubSectionTitle[#1]%
%\subsubsection{\CreateSectionTitle{}} %%% 
\begin{center}
\tablefirsthead{
\hline}
\tablehead{%
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize\sl myEnv \arabic{myCount} (continued)}\\
\hline}
\tabletail{%
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\scriptsize\sl continued on next page \dots}\\
\hline}
\tablelasttail{\hline}
\label{awf:\CasesKVMacroLabel}%
\begin{supertabular}{p{3.5cm}|p{11.5cm}}
\CreateNameLine
}{%
\end{supertabular}
\end{center}
\egroup  
}


\begin{document}



\begin{myEnv}[name={My title},label=label1]
    \variants{some variants to describe}
\end{myEnv}

\begin{myEnv}[label=label2]
    \variants{this only has variants of \ref{awf:label1}}
\end{myEnv}

\begin{myEnv}[name={But this has a title again}, label=label3]
    \variants{These are also variants of \ref{awf:label1}}
\end{myEnv}


\end{document}
```

Please note, that you have to say `name={This is a long title with whitespace}`, but it suffices to write in a single-word title `name=foo`

**Update: Version with correct counting of environment number**

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xkeyval}%

\usepackage{supertabular}

\newcounter{myCount}[section]
\makeatletter
\define@key{CasesFamilyKey}{name}[]{%
\def\CasesKVMacroName{#1}%
}%

\define@key{CasesFamilyKey}{label}[]{%
\def\CasesKVMacroLabel{#1}%
}%
\makeatother



\newcommand{\CreateNameLine}{%
\ifdef{\CasesKVMacroName}{%
Name & \CasesKVMacroName \tabularnewline
\hline
}{%
}%
}%

\newcommand{\CreateSubSubSectionTitle}[1][]{%
\setkeys{CasesFamilyKey}{#1}%
\ifdef{\CasesKVMacroName}{%
\addtocounter{myCount}{-1}% 
\subsubsection{\CasesKVMacroName}}
{%
\subsubsection{Env \arabic{myCount}}
}%
}%

\newcommand{\variants}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{l}{\emph{Variants:}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth}}{#1}\\
\hline}
% ...
\newcommand{\name}[1]{Name & #1\\ \hline}

\newenvironment{myEnv}[1][]{%
\setkeys{CasesFamilyKey}{#1}%
\refstepcounter{myCount}
\bgroup
\CreateSubSubSectionTitle[#1]%
%\subsubsection{\CreateSectionTitle{}} %%% 
\begin{center}
\tablefirsthead{
\hline}
\tablehead{%
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize\sl myEnv \arabic{myCount} (continued)}\\
\hline}
\tabletail{%
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\scriptsize\sl continued on next page \dots}\\
\hline}
\tablelasttail{\hline}
\label{awf:\CasesKVMacroLabel}%
\begin{supertabular}{p{3.5cm}|p{11.5cm}}
\CreateNameLine
}{%
\end{supertabular}
\end{center}
\egroup  
}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents%

\section{First}

\subsection{First sub}


\begin{myEnv}[name={My title},label=label1]
    \variants{some variants to describe}
\end{myEnv}

\begin{myEnv}[label=label2]
    \variants{this only has variants of \ref{awf:label1}}
\end{myEnv}

\subsubsection{A completely different subsubsection}

\begin{myEnv}[name={But this has a title again}, label=label3]
    \variants{These are also variants of \ref{awf:label1}}
\end{myEnv}

\section{Another one}

\subsection{Also another one}

\subsubsection{Yet another completely different subsubsection}


\begin{myEnv}[label=label5]
    \variants{These are also variants of \ref{awf:label4}}
\end{myEnv}

\begin{myEnv}[name={But this has a title again, but was shown already}, label=label4]
    \variants{These are also variants of \ref{awf:label3}}
\end{myEnv}


\begin{myEnv}[label=label6]
    \variants{These are also variants of \ref{awf:label4}}
\end{myEnv}

\begin{myEnv}[label=label7]
    \variants{These are also variants of \ref{awf:label4}}
\end{myEnv}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works quite well, however the counter that is used within the subsection title does not appear in the document's TOC (defaults to 0). It does count right in Title itself, though.

Comment: I will look later on, ok?

Comment: @jowlo: If I understand you correctly, you want the counter of your environment to be equal to the subsubsection (or subsection?) counter? I already wondered why the subsubsection and the environment should have different counters

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, i guess it's quite specific. The counters are not the same, since there could be a (subsub)section in between, where the environment is not used, or the same environment is used again in a completely different section while still the numbering of the environments (which is also used in the subsubsection's title) should not reset.

Comment: @jowlo: Sorry, but why did you not write that in the OP? If there is no section/subsection, the command `\thesubsubsection` will print `0.0.1` etc.  or even `0.0.0.1` etc. if the document class is `book` or something like that. Please specify, what should be in the TOC!

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding here, I expanded the example in the OP . The TOC should just display the standard, eg all sections, their subsections and subsubsections. Everytime the environment ist used, a standard subsubsection should be created, but the counter for the environments is not reset within the whole document.

Comment: I am still curious, how to do this, but in my case it should not be that big of a problem to leave out the environment-numbering in the title. I am marking yours as the answer, because it did solve the initial problem for getting the name into the subsubsection's title very well (and taught me what the `key-value` approach is). Thank you!

Comment: @jowlo: Although you have already accepted, I still want to solve the other problem too ;-)

Comment: @jowlo: I think, I have found the `error` - I have updated the code